# Is it always needed to go through bi-conditionals in separated steps when proving equivalence? Proving $A \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow B' \subseteq A'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of U, then $A \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow U-B \subseteq U-A$

$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x \in U-B \Rightarrow x \in U - A)$$
$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)((x \in U \land x \notin B) \Rightarrow (x \in U \land x \notin A))$$
$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)((x \notin U \lor x \in B) \lor (x \in U \land x \notin A))$$
$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)((x \in U \lor x \notin U \lor x \in B) \land (x \notin A \lor x \notin U \lor x \in B))$$
$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)( \top \land (x \notin U \lor (x \notin A \lor x \in B)))$$
$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x \notin U \lor (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B))$$
$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x \in U \Rightarrow (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B))$$
$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)((x \in U \land x \in A) \Rightarrow x \in B)$$
And as we have $A$ being a subset of $U$ we have also the following implication:
$$(\forall x)(x \in A \Rightarrow x\in U) \Rightarrow (\forall x)(x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in A \land x \in U)$$
Then we end with:
$$U - B \subseteq U-A \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B)$$
$$U-B \subseteq U - A \Leftrightarrow A \subseteq B$$

My doubts are if I can consider tautology to do simplifications and if it is right to prove equivalence without going through both bi-conditionals in separate steps, and if the solution is correct.

Comment: Yes, you can with equivalence without biconditinals

Comment: The use of bi-conditional is correct. Maybe I would simplify it going directly from line 1 to line 5 and then apply contraposition to get directly line 7.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA your approach seems to be very direct, i needed to do this way because i cant remember most equivalences from top of my head as a very beginner, i will take notes on your approach, the jump from line 1 to line 5 is easy to understand. and last step is a equivalence when negating both sides of a conditional provide the same logic value?

Comment: Yes, see [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)

Comment: The first equivalence is wrong because it lacks proper quantification.  P(x) is never the same as for all x, P(x).

Comment: To avoid that useless newfangled universal thingy, a clear  and equivalent problem to prove:  A,B subset S implies (S - B subset S - A iff A subset B).

Comment: I edited the problem as you stated here and tried to follow a similar approach as the first one. I will appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple direct proof.

A subset B iff
for all x, (x in A implies x in B) iff
for all x, (x not in B implies x not in A) iff
B' subset A'

What you have written is excessively complex and does not use well formed formulas (mathematical incoherent).

Is a temporary universal set some sort of neomath oxymoron?

Comment: Assuming temporarily that $U$ is an universal set, is something i take from Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis - Elliot Mendelson, maybe i used the world in the wrong sense but it is used the same words in the book, but it seems to be used as "Universe" in other texts. Can you point what is incoherent and show me how to fix?

Comment: Using i, the square root of minus one, for I is demonstrating an unwillingness to pay attention to details, an important skill in math and science.  I often ignore such  sloppy thinking. Both "implies not in A" and "or not in A" are both ill formed  formulas.  Symbolic logic does not allow English syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback i should pay more attention before submiting something or even asking what is the problem(when they obvious like these), i think it dont have more ill formed formulas now, but i got the point about non needed steps. I understood why your approach is a better way. So can you confirm my approach is correct now?

Comment: As I said, I often ignore those who write i when they mean I.  @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim

Comment: I just want to know if it is correct now.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim.  See comments original question.